# How can I use PostGIS to select the average price of the closest X locations?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I would like to find the average price of gas for any given home. Here are my current tables.

```
home_id  | geocoordinates
1        | 0101000020E61000005BB6D617097544
2        | 0101000020E61000005BB6D617097545
3        | 0101000020E61000005BB6D617097546
4        | 0101000020E61000005BB6D617097547
5        | 0101000020E61000005BB6D617097548

gas_price   |   geocoordinates
1           |   0101000020E61000005BB6D617097544
1           |   0101000020E61000005BB6D617097545
1           |   0101000020E61000005BB6D617097546
2           |   0101000020E61000005BB6D617097547
2           |   0101000020E61000005BB6D617097548
2           |   0101000020E61000005BB6D617097544
2           |   0101000020E61000005BB6D617097545
3           |   0101000020E61000005BB6D617097546
3           |   0101000020E61000005BB6D617097547
3           |   0101000020E61000005BB6D617097548
3           |   0101000020E61000005BB6D617097544
4           |   0101000020E61000005BB6D617097545
4           |   0101000020E61000005BB6D617097546
4           |   0101000020E61000005BB6D617097547
```

For each home, I would like to find the average gas price of the  X closest gas_prices. Example if X=5:

```
home_id     |   average_of_closest_five_gas_prices
1           |   1.5
2           |   2.5
3           |   2.1
4           |   1.5
5           |   1.5
```

I figured it out for using one individual home_id but I'm struggling to figure out how to do it for all.

```
select avg(gas_price) from (
                               SELECT *
                               FROM gas_price
                               ORDER BY gas_price.geocoordinates <-> '0101000020E61000005BB6D617097544'
                               LIMIT 5
                           ) as table_a
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Just edited with what I've tried. I'm struggling to figure out how to do it for ALL geocoordinates, not just one.

Comment: You can do a nested query for that. Just `SELECT home.home_id, … FROM home`, put your query in the `…`, and replace the hardcoded coordinate with `home.geocoordinates`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Is this the sort of thing a windows function could also be used for?

Comment: You could do a cross join and then a window function if there was a simpler matching criteria (like `price.geo <-> home.geo < 5`) but I can't think of anything for "the five nearest" off the top of my head.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [lateral join](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) to limit size of group in `group by`.

```
select home_id, avg(gas_price)
  from home,
    lateral (
      select gas_price
        from gas_price
        order by gas_price.geocoordinates <-> home.geocoordinates
        limit 5
    ) x
  group by home_id;
```

Another option is to use window function: partition by `home_id`, order by distance and select only rows with `row_number() <= 5`.

```
select home_id, avg(gas_price)
  from (
    select row_number() over w as r, *
      from home h, gas_price g
      window w as (partition by home_id order by g.geocoordinates <-> h.geocoordinates)
    ) x
  where r <= 5
  group by home_id;
```